Grammatical mistake in what is on-topic
At: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
It says:

Support questions for specific modules that aren't asking how to work
around bugs find in those modules

At a minimum, it should be:

Support questions for specific modules that aren't asking how to work
around bugs found in those modules

If further revisions are permitted, I think this is more clear:

Support questions about modules, except questions on how to work
around bugs found in those modules


I like that wording, and made the edit.
